# JSON array only gives "1" as length, cannot loop through

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following json array:

```
var champions = [{
  "1":{
    "name":"Aatrox",
    "role1":"Top",
    "role2":"Jungle"},
  "2":{
    "name":"Ahri",
    "role1":"Middle"},
  "3":{"
    name":"Akali",
    "role1":"Middle",
    "role2":"Top"
   }
}];
```

and I trying to loop through this array with a code snippet I found:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < champions.length; i++) {
        console.log(champions[i][x].name);
        x++;
    }
});
```

But it only gives me "Aatrox" and stops as `champions.length` is 1.
How can I loop through the array for all names?

Comment: because your array contains only one object

Comment: It is not just an array. It is a single element array with various numbered properties (on that single element).

Comment: console.log(champions[0][i].name); will work. first depth is the array.

Comment: you are looping in an array with only one element, and that element actually contains three elements.

Comment: so what is the right way to loop through this? `console.log(champions[0][i].name);` does not work. I have no idea how the `for` needs to look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you do not wish to change your data structure, you can iterate the array and then the properties of each object within it (then access the name):

```
var champions = [{
  "1":{
    "name":"Aatrox",
    "role1":"Top",
    "role2":"Jungle"},
  "2":{
    "name":"Ahri",
    "role1":"Middle"},
  "3":{
      "name":"Akali",
    "role1":"Middle",
    "role2":"Top"
   }
}];

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < champions.length; i++) {
        for (var prop in champions[i]){
            console.log(champions[i][prop].name);
        }
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/234yspw1/

Note: The order they are returned is undefined, so you should not count on that.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/234yspw1/1/

If order *is* important you need to restructure your data to be an array.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:  Working JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/3ms8s9jr/

```js
var champions = [{
  "1":{
    "name":"Aatrox",
    "role1":"Top",
    "role2":"Jungle"},
  "2":{
    "name":"Ahri",
    "role1":"Middle"},
  "3":{"
    name":"Akali",
    "role1":"Middle",
    "role2":"Top"
   }
}];
```

needs to be:

```js
var champions = [
  {
    "name":"Aatrox",
    "role1":"Top",
    "role2":"Jungle"
  },
  {
    "name":"Ahri",
    "role1":"Middle"
  },
  { 
    "name":"Akali",
    "role1":"Middle",
    "role2":"Top"
  }
];
```

You need to have one object per champion, right now you have them all stored in one big object, so you can't loop through it easily (rather, it's just awkward to do it effectively).

Ideally you want to have your data in a format that is easy to use, so converting the data if you need to into an array is probably going to be the best long term option.

Loop through that like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < champions.length; i++) {
        console.log(champions[i].name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course you can iterate the properties of the one object. Just not the outer array. You should not need to change the data to match the code.

Comment: The data structure is awkward, is all your data in that format?  If so just pull out the data from the object and push it to an array.

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* As everyone has pointed out, your data structure is a little odd. The best idea is to make sure your array is correctly structured so that you can iterate it as an array, but you can also iterate an array containing a single object:

jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) does a good job of iterating objects & keys:

```
if(champions.length) {
    $.each(champions[0], function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.name);
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L580zfn2/)

Answer (score 2):

It's an array of length one. Iterate objects like so:

```
var champs = champions[0]
var keys = Object.keys(champs)

// if you need them in order
keys = keys.map(Number).sort().map(String)

// iterate
keys.forEach(function (key, index) {
   console.log(key)           // "1"
   console.log(champs[key])   // { "name": "etc" }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop this array

```
var champions = [{
  "1":{
    "name":"Aatrox",
    "role1":"Top",
    "role2":"Jungle"},
  "2":{
    "name":"Ahri",
    "role1":"Middle"},
  "3":{"
    name":"Akali",
    "role1":"Middle",
    "role2":"Top"
   }
}];
```

Your code will need to look like this

```
for( var i = 0, end = champions.length; i < end; i++ ){
  for( var attr in champions[i] ){
    if( !champions[i].hasOwnProperty( attr ) ){
      continue
    }
    // champions[i][attr] is the champion here
  }
```

Alternateley, you can convert your odd looking json to a regular array with this rather strange looking bit of code.

```
var championsArray = Array.prototype.splice.call( champions[0] )
```

Then loop through it normally.

Comment: *"`for( var i in champions )`"* Best to avoid using `for-in` to loop through arrays (without safeguards); that's not what it's for. (The *inner* loop is fine, though.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ive ran into problems with for-in lately and was wondering what the correct usage of it is? I never really worked out what the issue was... I simply changed to a for loop and things worked!

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: [Or my answer on the topic...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) :-)